# Postgresql plpgsql multiple row loop

Tags: postgresql, loops, stored-procedures, cursor, plpgsql

I'm busy trying to rewrite an Informix stored procedure for a PostgreSQL
database and I am stuck on something that is probably quite obvious to
everyone who know PostgreSQL.

I have my sql script as follows

```
-- ensure type and function get created
drop type if exists tp_users cascade;
drop function if exists sp_cmplist();

-- create type
create type tp_users as (
    us_id       char(30),
    us_status   char(1)
);

create function sp_cmplist()
    returns tp_users as $$
declare
    lr_users   tp_users;
begin

    for lr_users in
        select users.us_id, users.us_status
        from users
    loop
        return lr_users;
    end loop;

end

$$ language 'plpgsql';

select sp_cmplist();
```

this is just a dummy script to select from an imaginary users table but how would I use this script with a cursor or loop to make sure all results are returned?

Comment: Better suited at: http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I've tried the database administrators community before but they've shut me down with questions like this saying that it's not professional enough or something like that

Comment: The stackoverflow is good place - plpgsql is a developer topic

Answer (score 0):

This code works:

```
CREATE TABLE foo(a int);
INSERT INTO foo VALUES(10),(20);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION retfoo()
RETURNS SETOF foo AS $$
BEGIN
  RETURN QUERY SELECT * FROM foo;
  RETURN;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

postgres=# SELECT * FROM retfoo();
┌────┐
│ a  │
├────┤
│ 10 │
│ 20 │
└────┘
(2 rows)
```

Time: 1.143 ms

Answer (score 0):

I may have answered my own question with the following

```
drop type if exists tp_users cascade;
drop function if exists sp_cmplist();

create type tp_users as (
    us_id        text,
    us_status    text,
    lv_nothing   text,
    lv_cnt       int
);

create function sp_cmplist()
    returns setof tp_users as $$
declare
    lr_users   tp_users;
    lv_cnt     int;
begin

    lv_cnt := 0;

    for lr_users in
        select users.us_id, users.us_status
        from users
    loop

        -- increment this counter for testing purposes
        lv_cnt              := lv_cnt + 1;

        lr_users.lv_nothing := 'yupy';
        lr_users.lv_cnt     := lv_cnt;

        return next lr_users;

    end loop;

    return;

end

$$ language 'plpgsql';

select * from sp_cmplist();
```

this seems to work perfectly

Comment: for this request you don't need `for` cycle. It is slower than `RETURN QUERY SELECT use_id, us_status, 'yupy', row_number() over () FROM users;`. What is possible to solve by simple query should be solved by simple query.

Comment: Normally this is the way I would do it with the returned variables being a table but this example is just a dummy query, the real query is using multiple separate selects and comparing results and building up the data for the return in the loop, I don't think I'd be able to do it easily with one select